How to handle the Chunk Load Error in JavaScript -React Webpack project
I am working on a React Webpack project . I have done the minification and the JS files will be loaded in chunks .
Since we have dynamic imports , Chunk Load Error rarely occurs when the browser encounters an error in fetching some JavaScript files.
How to handle these errors ? I was able to reproduce or see this error happening only once ( I assume it was due to cache ) when we refresh the page it is gone. what are the better ways to handle this ?
I have added Error Boundary to handle the exception. however that doesnt fix the problem . it only handles the exception.

I hope the errors are caused primary due to caching. In that case, you could use the  error handler (window.onerror) and reloading if message has chunk load message.
